# Problema assinatura NFS-e - Remessa adulterada após a assinatura

Tags: xml, ruby-on-rails, nfe, certificado-digital

Estou desenvolvendo a emissão de NFS-e para a cidade de Gaspar-SC via web service, na qual utiliza a empresa Thema para processamento das notas.

Estou com problemas ao assinar a NFS-e onde está retornando o erro:
**E515 - Erro ao validar assinatura. - Remessa adulterada após a assinatura.**

Já desenvolvi a assinatura de NFS-e para outras cidades utilizando o mesmo método de assinatura e está funcionando perfeitamente.

Gostaria de saber qual o procedimento utilizado para gerar a assinatura. Qual a String(XML) que devo utilizar para assinar o RPS e o LOTE RPS.

Atualmente estou assinando o Rps com a tag `<InfRps id="XXX">...</InfRps>` e o LoteRps com o conteúdo da tag `<LoteRps id="XXX">...</LoteRps>`.

Quando assino o `LoteRps` já está incluso na String todos os RPS's já assinados.

Segue o XML na qual estou tentando assinar (já está separado e comentando cada etapa das assinaturas):

[envio_rps.xml](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5AANOYccxOBWjIxLXhQbHZYMDQ)